# How to install theano with python3.6?

Tags: python, theano, conda

I am using `conda` to install theano with python3.6 but got below error:

```
$ conda install theano
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 3.6*
  - theano -> python 2.7* -> openssl 1.0.1*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

It seems that theano doesn't work with python3.6. Is this a way for me to install it with python3.6?

Comment: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/6155

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no conda package for theano on Python 3.6:

https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/

You can chose from 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5.

Alternatively you can build Theano from source using `pip`:

```
pip install Theano
```

Comment: As of May 2018, it seems that there is a `theano` conda package

Comment: I tried to install the conda package on python 3.6, it crashed the conda CMD, and basically wrecked the environment. Tried again with a clean env. only the pre-reqs. as on the theano website, same result.

Answer (score 2):

**Installation of theano/pymc3 with python 3.6 for windows 10**

I've had serious problems to find an installation that makes pymc3 work properly. With "import pymc3" I've got a fatal error usually. According to the many blog contributions - which I tested all.... - it does seem to be a procedure not completely stable yet. BUT: based on the Anaconda distribution the follwing did work for me (**for Jupyter also**):

(*see also: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html*)

1. conda install theano
2. conda install pygpu
3. pip install pymc3 (*pip necessary when using python 3.6*)

Answer (score 0):

No conda package for this library.

use `pip install Theano`

You may need to add sudo before the pip command to install into your system’s site-packages directory. If you do not have administrator access to your machine, you can install Theano locally (to ~/.local) using

`pip install Theano --user`

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#

Comment: OP is using conda, which always has conda environments. No sudo required.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6 requires pip3 to install Theano package.

```
$git clone git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
$cd Theano
$sudo pip3 install -e .
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install theano on Python 3.6 if you want you can choose one of the versions below:

```
Python == 2.7* or ( >= 3.3 and < 3.6 )
```